# Reverse sort the number having repeated value

Tags: javascript

I have to sort the input number who digits are not distinct.
I've tried this code. But does not work for repeated digit number.

```
function abc(n){
   return +n.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
   //take n=1021 it will return 1201, instead of 2110
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any sorting implemented in your logic:

```js
function abc(n) {
  return +n.toString().split('').sort().reverse().join('');
}

console.log(abc(1021)); // prints "2110"
```

Or, if you're only targeting browsers that support the [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) function:

```js
function abc(n) {
  return Array.from(String(n), Number).sort().reverse().join('');
};

console.log(abc(1021));
```

Comment: actually I've returned sort((a, b) =>return a - b) instead of  sort((a, b) =>a - b); anyways thanks.

Comment: There's no need for the return statement if your arrow function body consists of a single expression.

Comment: Ok! I didn't knew that :)

Comment: why converting to number, when `sort()` is using sort by string?

Comment: @NinaScholz Learned something new today. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Beside using `reverse` after sorting, you could sort directly descending and omit reversing.

```js
function desc(n) {
    return [...n.toString()].sort((a, b) => b - a).join('');
}

console.log(desc(1021)); // '2110'
```